# How to choose different words to be shown using if statement?

Tags: c, function, if-statement

Whenever I make **ch[index]==0**, it gives me first word from text file but whenever I select **ch[index]==1**, it gives me nothing. How to make this if statement working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE * fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt","r");
    char ch[100];
    int index = 0;

    if(fr != NULL){
       while((ch[index] = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){
        if(index[ch]==1){                              // here is if statement
            if(ch[index] == ' ') {
                ch[index] = '\0';
                printf("Here is your %s: \n",ch); 
                index = 0;
             }
              else { index++; }
           }
       }
      fclose(fr);
    }
        else{ printf("Unable to read file."); }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why specifically `i < 8`?

Comment: That for loop is useless, you can just as well remove it

Comment: Also, please note that your `while` is an infinite loop. `ch[index]` is a `char`, but `EOF` is an `int` outside the range of `char`, it will never compare true.

Comment: It is still not working after removing for loop.

Comment: `index` is not an array you can't have the statment `index[ch]`

Comment: The OP tried to modify the question to remove the useless for loop but injected a few more bugs in the code. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that should work and show the second word, although I didn't test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h> //not needed

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "r");
    char ch[100];
    int index = 0, c, i = 0;
    //for loop is useless
    if (fr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to read file.");
        return 0;
        //I prefer error checking without a giant if statement, but it's up to you
    }
    c = fgetc(fr); //fgetc() returns an int, not char
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        ch[index] = c;
        if (ch[index] == ' ')
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                ch[index] = '\0';
                printf("Here is your string: %s\n", ch); //The format seemed weird to me, that's why I changed it, use what you need
            }
            index = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else
            index++;
        c = fgetc(fr);
    }
    fclose(fr);
    //return 0; //not needed in C99 or later
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start you have an `fclose(fr)` inside your i loop, but then you never open the file again.  You are also incrementing `i` inside the loop a second time, which is never good in practice.

try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
  fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt","r");
  index = 0;
    if(fr != NULL){
```

and remove the fopen from the top.

There is probably a better way than opening and closing the file on each loop iteration.

Comment: And now the question changed while I've been answering it.